# Sample dataframe by value in column and keep all rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sample

I want to sample a Pandas dataframe using values in a certain column, but I want to keep all rows with values that are in the sample.

For example, in the dataframe below I want to randomly sample some fraction of the values in `b`, but keep **all** corresponding rows in `a` and `c`.

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(1, 101, 1),'b': list(range(0, 100, 4))*4, 'c' :list(range(0, 100, 2))*2} )
```

Desired example output from a 16% sample:

```
Out[66]: 
     a   b   c
0    1   0   0
1   26   0  50
2   51   0   0
3   76   0  50
4    4  12   6
5   29  12  56
6   54  12   6
7   79  12  56
8   18  68  34
9   43  68  84
10  68  68  34
11  93  68  84
12  19  72  36
13  44  72  86
14  69  72  36
15  94  72  86
```

I've tried sampling the series and merging back to the main data, like this:

```
In [66]: pd.merge(d, d.b.sample(int(.16 * d.b.nunique())))
```

This creates the desired output, but it seems inefficient. My real dataset has millions of values in `b` and hundreds of millions of rows. I know I could also use some version of ``isin```, but that also is slow.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried passing a value for the `frac` parameter instead? Maybe the implementation is faster than finding unique values.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html

Comment: can you share the data you're working with (uploading it to google drive or github)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the data because they are protected under privacy laws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really doubt that `isin` is slow:

```
uniques = df.b.unique()

# this maybe the bottle neck
samples = np.random.choice(uniques, replace=False, size=int(0.16*len(uniques)) )

# sampling here
df[df.b.isin(samples)]
```

You can profile the steps above. In case `samples=...` is slow, you can try:

```
idx = np.random.rand(len(uniques))
samples = uniques[idx<0.16]
```

Those took about 100 ms on my system on 10 million rows.

**Note**: `d.b.sample(int(.16 * d.b.nunique()))` does not sample `0.16` of the unique values in `b`.

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain what you mean by your Note that d.b.sample() doesn't sample .16 of the unique values in b? This seems to work for my example

Comment: @svenkatesh that code breaks into `n=int(.16 * d.b.nunique()); d.b.sample(n)`.  `d.b.sample` doesn't care about the values inside the series `d.b`, and `0.16 * d.b.nunique()` is just a number.  So the command just sample randomly from the series without caring about the unique values. That is, if you have `100` rows with `b==10`, maybe `16` rows of them get picked.